# how can I change src of 3 image with a button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

how can I change src of 3 image with a button in reactjs?

it changes function for dark to light mode.

```
  const switchTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    setTheme(newTheme);
  };
```

```
<button onClick={() => { switchTheme();}} className="buttonMode">
```

but after that, I should change the src of the image to a white one.

```
<img id="logo" src={"/LOGO.svg"} alt="" />
```

LOGO.SVG to LOGOBLACK.svg.

How can I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator, just like you did with the `newTheme`

```
<img id="logo" src={theme === "light" ? "/Logo.svg" : "/LogoBlack.svg"}
```

Comment: worked great thanks !